# Add from:to range per group as a column

Tags: r

I am currently struggling with a dataset. I have some fundamental values of different companies for different years. I want to add the years to that dataset.

```
Current dataset:
FirmA  EBITDA
FirmA  EBITDA
FirmA  EBITDA
FirmB  EBITDA
FirmB  EBITDA
FirmB  EBITDA
```

Goal is to add the dates, whereas I know that the first entry of FirmA is 2017, the second is 2016 and the third 2015 and it repeats without exceptions.

```
2017 FirmA  EBITDA
2016 FirmA  EBITDA
2015 FirmA  EBIDTA
2017 FirmB  EBITDA
2016 FirmB  EBITDA
2015 FirmB  EBITDA
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?
I am using R but if there is an easy solution in Python or Excel I am open to try it out.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of R's [recycling rule](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Recycling-rules)

```
transform(df, year = 2017:2015)
#     V1     V2 year
#1 FirmA EBITDA 2017
#2 FirmA EBITDA 2016
#3 FirmA EBITDA 2015
#4 FirmB EBITDA 2017
#5 FirmB EBITDA 2016
#6 FirmB EBITDA 2015
```

or simply

```
df$year <- 2017:2015
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "FirmA  EBITDA
FirmA  EBITDA
FirmA  EBITDA
FirmB  EBITDA
FirmB  EBITDA
FirmB  EBITDA", header  = F)
```

Comment: plus1up: like suggested `df$year <- 2017:2015` this method uses recycling.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use `data.table`

```
# I used sample data from @Maurits Evers
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, year:= paste(2017:2015), by = V1]
```

And the output

```
      V1     V2 year
1: FirmA EBITDA 2017
2: FirmA EBITDA 2016
3: FirmA EBITDA 2015
4: FirmB EBITDA 2017
5: FirmB EBITDA 2016
6: FirmB EBITDA 2015
```